# How to remove the dates with zero values - EXCEL

Tags: excel

i am trying to remove the date graph but unable to do it.

[image: reference image]

below steps i tried

1. Remove that particular data value from the select data horizontal category still unable to remove from the graph
2. tried formatting the cell (#,"") value still unable to remove from the graph.

kindly help me on this.

Comment: tried  [ select cell > r-click > format > M-D-YYYY ] ?         (I'm assuming the data is excel date formatted)

Comment: Thanks for your response Yes it's in date format. I tried that. Still able to see the data in graph.

Comment: does applying M-D-YYYY to custom format work?

Comment: Not working my friend.

Comment: In the first date, try adding a single quote (`'`) in front of the date, then hiding the lines with `N/A` instead of data

Comment: When I add a single quote at front. Formatting is changing to DD-MM-YYYY. If I removed that cell also unwanted data can be seen in the graph

Comment: your target is to "remove the dates with zero values", but your data is 'NA' text. What happen (to the graph) if you just remove the value ? If removing the whole line? Is the actual value for that date is zero (as per OP title..) ?

Comment: I am getting NA in the axis. And zero value in graph.

Comment: What happen (to the graph) if 'NA' in the cell is deleted manually?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just filter your data frame by column B, and uncheck "NA" before inserting the graph?

Comment: Data is automatically generated in graph so that is also not working.